# Creating DLL and using it from Excel

Tags: c++, excel

I have the following issue when trying to create a DLL in CPP and using it in Excel. When the argument reaches the CPP function, the value it holds changes (regardless of what it was in Excel). I am guessing somewhere it "drops", but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Here is the code:

**Source.cpp**

```
extern "C" double __stdcall my_double(double A)
{
    return 2.0 * A; 
}
```

**Source.def**

```
LIBRARY
EXPORTS
    my_double
```

**VBA Code**

```
Declare PtrSafe Function my_double Lib "C:\MyDir\Example.dll" (ByVal A As Double) As Double
```

Then when I call `my_double` from excel, it always returns 0.0.

I attached a debug point to the function, and I can see that the value is indeed 0 when it reaches the cpp function. Any tips on how to debug this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Things I have tried so far without success:

- Made sure the bits on excel and the build in CPP match (both x64).
- Tried with Release mode and Debug mode.
- Tried changing the VBA code with `ByVal`, `ByRef` and using neither.
- Tried a simpler example using `int` instead of `double`.
- I checked `DUMPBIN` in the DLL file I created, and it looks OK.
- I was following this tutorial: https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/Andrew.Hazel/EXCEL_C++.pdf (page 54)

Comment: Try adding __declspec(dllexport) to the source.  You will also need to add a DLLMain that returns TRUE.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain

Comment: @cup At a loose end, I replicated the OP's C++ code and it worked fine (Visual Studio compilation). For this simple function you don't strictly need a DLLMain (no static objects to initialize etc), and since the OP has a .def file, then the __declspec(dllexport) is unnecessary. I tested it with a VBA sub-routine and the same function declaration as the OP, and the number was doubled and returned. Perhaps the OP could add their VBA test code to the question, as that is the only difference I can see?

Comment: @DS_London For VBA I did the following: Inserted a module in VBA, and wrote this single line of code: `Declare PtrSafe Function my_double Lib "C:\MyDir\Example.dll" (ByVal A As Double) As Double` and I can see that it attaches to correct function in CPP since I can put a debug point. The issue is that it zero's out the input... I am wondering if something is off with my configuration in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel will struggle to use a function declared directly from a dll entry point as it doesn't know the types of the parameters (and other things, eg how to manage the memory of the return value). The OP's method from the tutorial may have worked in the past, but not any more it seems.

Creating a VBA user-defined function (UDF) wrapper gets around this, as Excel knows how to handle and marshal parameters in this case:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function my_double Lib "C:\Users\david\source\repos\CppTests\x64\Release\DllForExcel.dll" (ByVal A As Double) As Double

Public Function MyDouble(d As Double) As Double
    MyDouble = my_double(d)
End Function
```

Use the `MyDouble()` function in the spreadsheet.

The other solution is to go down the route of creating a compiled Xll (often using the Excel SDK), which has entry points to register functions and their parameters, as well as managing memory allocations.

Comment: Thank you ! this worked indeed. I would also upvote your answer, but I dont have enough reputation.